# React useEffect hook doesn't trigger when a dependency changes

Tags: reactjs

I have this useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mark useEffect', compatibleProducts);
    if (Object.keys(compatibleProducts.rims).length === 0
            && Object.keys(compatibleProducts.tires).length === 0) return;

}, [compatibleProducts,...]);
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture the state with the (COMPATIBLE_PRODUCTS) changes at the last line. In the state I check, indeed values are added, but the useEffect hook doesn't trigger again.

Any reason why it does this ?

State before: [image]
State after: [image]

Reducer  action:
[image]

Comment: Is this redux? Can you show us the reducer where you mutate the state? The fact that you see the action running does not mean that you are returning a new state (mutating the current state is wrong).

Comment: @keul I have edited my question

Comment: the object identity of your array 'compatibleProducts' stays the same. you can either copy the contents `compatibleProducts: [...action.compatibleProducts]` or spread it into the deps array `useEffect(() => {}, [...compatibleProducts]`

Comment: @Martin good answer but don't you mean the following: 

`useEffect(() => {}, [{...compatibleProducts}]`

Because `useEffect(() => {}, [...compatibleProducts]` Gives me the error `Type 'CompatibleProductsInterface' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`. Even so, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should try
in reducer

```js
case TYPE.COMPATIBLE_PRODUCTS.SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                compatibleProducts: {
                    ...state.compatibleProducts,
                    ...action.compatibleProducts,
                    timespan: + new Date()
                }
            }
```

in your component

```js
useEffect(() => {
    ...
}, [compatibleProducts.timespan]);
```